# Help with ID of an electrical connector

Tags: pcb

This is for a GE refrigerator control board.

It is fairly close to a Molex 496 KK series (6 position) pn# 0009508063 
However, that particular part has taller posts along the side & the ramp is too tall and thus interferes with the plug when trying to plug in.

I'm needing to ID the connector marked "ORG". 
The back has a marking of AMP.

The measurements that i'm sure of are: 
Pitch = 3.96mm
length = 23.81mm 
width = 6.45mm (8.59 including the post)
hight = 16.96mm

It would be a great help if one of you can help point me in the right direction. 
Thanks so much!

[Photos](https://www.flickr.com/photos/57148282@N06/shares/e5387Z)

Comment: Use a file or some sand paper?

Comment: Amp is a brand/model of TE connectivity btw.

Comment: Thanks, for the input. I can defiantly get it to work as a one off, but this is a piece of a larger project and will be making them in the thousands so I need to streamline if possible.   Also, needs to look as stock as possible.

Comment: There we go!  Thanks for the tip. I guess it is in fact TE Connectivity vs Molex.  Thanks for the help!  http://sg.element14.com/te-connectivity-amp/770849-6/wire-board-connector-receptacle/dp/4981273

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, AMP is a known brand/model of TE Connectivity. OP then found the appropriate connecter, the 6 pin version of 770849.